# How to run a command before BUILD_EXECUTABLE is called in Android?

Tags: android, build, makefile, cmake

I am building droid-VNC-server on Android-4.0.4 (https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server). This app uses cmake to create some header files. The Android.mk simply builds some binaries with the `BUILD_EXECUTABLE` Android definition. But first I need to run cmake in an inner directory `droidvncdaemon/vnc/libvncserver-kanaka`.

1. I tried to use `CleanSpec.mk`, but its usage is mainly to clean
   `out/` directory before building.
2. I tried to add a shell command with `$(shell ...)` but I don't know
   how to make a dependency to the `BUILD_EXECUTABLE` target.
3. Probably I should create
   `droidvncdaemon/vnc/libvncserver-kanaka/Android.mk`, but I don't
   know what to put in to run a simple cmake command, and make the
   `droidvncdaemon/vnc/Android.mk` depends on it.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake-based applications can be build for Android without any change. Get the toolchain from  http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/
and pass it to your cmake command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./path/to/android.toolchain.cmake ./path/to/your/source/tree
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's it. I needed to follow everything in android-cmake doc to build it. It worked :-), although I tried to give it the ndk folders from AOSP official sources, without success. Then I don't understand what the `ndk/` and `prebuilt/ndk` folders in AOSP official build are used for. I mean they don't contain the whole ndk stuff, and cmake just doesn't like that...

Comment: **ndk** directory in AOSP contains sources necessary to build NDK.